# Too many initializer value eror

Tags: c++, dll

I am just a beginner in coding. I know the basics of c++ and c#. I was making a dll injector. I also followed a tutorial for a part. One part of the thing I have from the tutorial has an error and it is "Too many initializer values". I don't know what that means and why it is there. The error is at the `nullptr` in the next line
`void* allocated_memory(h_process, nullptr, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);`
It is at the first `nullptr`. If I remove that nullptr then I get the error at the `MAX_PATH`

biggest part of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <libloaderapi.h>

void get_id(const char* windows_title, DWORD &process_id) 
{
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(NULL, windows_title), &process_id);
}

void error(const char* error_title, const char* error_message)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, error_message, error_title, NULL);
    exit(-1);
}

bool file_exists(std::string file_name)
{
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(file_name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    DWORD proc_id = NULL;
    char dll_path(MAX_PATH);
    const char* dll_name = "PW";
    const char* window_title = "Pixel Worlds";

    if (!file_exists(dll_name))
    {
        error("file_exists", "Something went wrong");
    }
    HANDLE h_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, proc_id);
    void* allocated_memory(h_process, nullptr, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    HANDLE h_thread = CreateRemoteThread(h_process, nullptr, NULL, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(LoadLibraryA), allocated_memory, NULL, nullptr);

    CloseHandle(h_process);
    VirtualFreeEx(h_process, allocated_memory, NULL, MEM_RELEASE);
    MessageBox(NULL, "Successfully injected", "Success", NULL);
}
```

Comment: You may want `void* allocated_memory = some_name_of_function_to_call_here(h_process, nullptr, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);`

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: I added the whole code too @AlanBirtles

Comment: I think Mike's guess is correct you are missing the function name and assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use the [VirtualAllocEx WinAPI routine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex) but you have not named that function in your attempted call, which is just incorrect syntax.

In place of the line:

```cpp
void* allocated_memory(h_process, nullptr, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

you need to declare your `void*` pointer and allocate the memory it points to with a call like the following:

```cpp
void* allocated_memory = VirtualAllocEx(h_process, nullptr, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```